# Is the SanDisk ULLtraDIMM secure after power-down?

Tags: hardware, storage

I found an interesting product last night called the [SanDisk ULLtradDimm SSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ULLtraDIMM) ([product page](http://www.sandisk.com/enterprise/ulltradimm-ssd/)), which essentially claims drastic performance gains by plugging an SSD into a standard DDR3 memory channel.

As one of the features of this product is data retention after power loss, does this imply that otherwise secure data (such as encryption keys) would be accessible after a power-loss scenario, or am I missing some aspect of this which would prevent arbitrary access to data?

My thought is that operating systems aren't built to distinguish between this sort of product and traditional RAM, so the data stored on the device would be immediately accessible on power-up. However, the details are far closer to the bare metal than I'm experienced in, so I can't say for sure.

Comment: Something's amiss here. You don't use flash for RAM since wear and tear and bit rot will bite you from behind. What matters here is the speed of the interface (bandwidth) and length of the wires (latency). While using flash for permanent storage all usual terms and conditions apply.

Comment: @DeerHunter Here's something that might help you understand from the Wikipedia page: "UEFI/BIOS updates are required to properly recognize an ULLtraDIMM in the system as a block device and not halt the bootstrap sequence."